# InfoPath 2013 to replace formated SSRS reports of Single SharePoint List items?

Tags: infopath, custom-list, xslt, custom-form, reporting-services

New to Infopath.

Can we natually and easily  use Infopath 2013 to do the following with SharePoint:

Format SharePoint List Data on a sharePoint WebPart web page for a single SP List item (determined by a query string ID=) .  This  infopath form won't accept input in any way, but will have URLs Links that pass List item column information .

I'm asking becasue we have a lot of this in MOSS 2007 using SSRS and we are looking to move to o365/SPO and want to know if InfoPath 2013 can offer this functinality.  I attempt to build one, but am new to Infpath and was lost.

If so, at a high level what would my steps be?

I attempted  Infopath Designer 2013 > New > Blank form > Data > SP List > added fields, but get textboxes that don't show the fields... so it appears the form (no treport) is in List New Mode.

If not InfoPath 2013, now that we've lost Design view on the DataView Web Part in SPD, any other good/easy way to format List Display page XSLT if the goal is to format List data in a very specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High level steps for an InfoPath browser form:

You don't need any fields in the main data source, but you need a secondary data source to the list, including all the fields you want to show in the form.

You will need code to get a URL parameter into the InfoPath form. There is a plug-in for InfoPath from Qdabra Software called "qRules" that loads DLL's into an IP form, so you can just use a specific command instead of writing the code yourself. qRules is not free, but does not cost much, especially if you want to avoid writing code yourself.

Once you have the ID from the URL parameter, set the query field of the secondary data source to the ID from the URL, then query the list. These rules can run when the form loads, after the qRules or code has run to get the URL parameter.

Drag the secondary data source onto the canvas and arrange as desired. Set all the controls to be read only or set the whole view to be read only. There is no risk of the user changing the data, because writing back to a SharePoint list from an IP browser form involves special code, too. But unless you set the controls to read only, the user might get the impression that they can actually edit the data.